# Ruby on Rails3: Why is this field not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do some TDD, and when I implemented this method, it's saying that self.state is an undefined method.

```
def init
    self.state = Array.new(NUM_SQUARES) if not self.state
     .
     .
```

but in the schema it shows:

```
create_table "boards", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "state"
    t.integer  "turn"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

my method initiating the error:

```
def setup
    @board = Board.new
    @board.save
    @board.init
end
```

Comment: What is self in this context? Where is the self.state= method being called?

Comment: oh, from init.. updating post

Comment: Are you sure the migration has been run? try in a console: Board.new.state. But why do you try to set an array to state (which is a string)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if you `@board.init` before you `@board.save`. `Board#init` modifies it, but it doesn't get saved, and that could be your problem. Thus, #setup should look something like this:

```
 def setup
      @board = Board.new
      @board.init
      @board.save
 end
```

Is there some other reason you `#save` before you `#init`?

Comment: as it turns out, i forgot to rake db:test:prepare. thanks. =\